# Among MySQL 5.5.X versions which is a production release?

Tags: mysql

we are doing a performance based test on MySQL5.5 but we chaotic about which version of MySQL5.5.X is for production release ie:(Mysql 5.5.9 or Mysql5.5.11)?.

Advance in Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly certain MySQL 5.5.11 is your answer.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,415648